# Return Rows Random and then Order By

Tags: mysql

I have this query that returns the results by ordering it by focus.name ASC. I would like to expand on this by first ordering it by rand() then ordering it by focus.name and limiting it by 10.

```
SELECT * FROM vendor_products WHERE 
vendor_products.focus_id IN (SELECT focus.id FROM focus WHERE
focus.name=? AND 
mydelete='0' ORDER BY focus.name ASC) AND product_id=? 
AND mydelete='0' ORDER BY focus_id ASC
```

Comment: Ordering anything after ordering by rand() is same as only ordering by rand()

Comment: I would like to randomize the results and then order the random results by name limit 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this

```
select t1.* 
from table t1, (select id from table order by rand() limit 10) t2
where t1.id = T2.id
order by t1.name
```

see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9a82/3)